# jquery hide/show all tr that contains word with checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to filter the results in one table with 1 checkbox that when its checked to hide trs that contains word ("Foo") and show them back when you uncheck the checkbox.Any help will be appreciated

Comment: have u tried anything or make any fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#check_box").click(function(){
    $( "tr:contains('foo')" ).toggle();
});
```

Comment: When i tried it in jsfiddle it seems to work fine but when i paste it in my code it is not working :/ http://pastebin.com/bxZD4XJv

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector. Like this:

```
$('tr:contains(foo)').hide()
```